# How do I access a promoted widget's UI elements in code using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-designer

So I created a class DemoPromotedWidget, it inherits from QWidget.

I then created a Widget in the designer, added a label to said widget called DemoLabel, & promoted the widget to class DemoPromotedWidget... Then I moved it to my toolbox, and it's now under "Scratchpad".

Normally, using Qt's designer, I can access ANY elements in the UI file in it's corresponding class file. However, in DemoPromotedWidget I can not.

Is there anyway for me to access DemoLabel inside of DemoPromotedWidget so that I can call something like...

```
ui->DemoPromotedWidget->setText("Updated Text");
```

Here is a picture of my UI Designer, with the DemoPromotedWidget already added.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7cLX.png

DemoPromotedWidget.h

```
#ifndef DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H
#define DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class DemoPromotedWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DemoPromotedWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H
```

DemoPromotedWidget.cpp

```
#include "demopromotedwidget.h"

DemoPromotedWidget::DemoPromotedWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    // How do I access DemoPromotedWidget->DemoLabel->setText()?????????????????????
}
```

Here is my mainwindow.ui...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>711</width>
    <height>418</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="DemoPromotedWidget" name="DemoPromotedWidget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>160</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>381</width>
      <height>191</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: black;
text-align: center;</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="DemoLabel">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>5</y>
       <width>381</width>
       <height>181</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">color: white;
text-align: center;</string>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>DemoLabel</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>711</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>DemoPromotedWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header>demopromotedwidget.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: You can show an image of the Object Inspector that is to the right of Qt designer.

Comment: share your .ui.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have updated my post with the image & my base classes.

Comment: @drescherjm just added it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use the name of the class with the name of the widget, so the first thing to do is change its name:

[image]

## first option:

On the other hand that the `QLabel` this inside the `DemoPromotedWidget` does not imply that `DemoPromotedWidget` can access the `QLabel` and less in the constructor since in that method it is not yet added to the main window, a possible solution is to create an attribute where you can assign it the `QLabel`:

**demopromotedwidget.h**

```
#ifndef DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H
#define DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QWidget>

class DemoPromotedWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DemoPromotedWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    QLabel *getLabel() const;
    void setLabel(QLabel *value);
private:
    QLabel *label;
};

#endif // DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H
```

**demopromotedwidget.cpp**

```
#include "demopromotedwidget.h"

DemoPromotedWidget::DemoPromotedWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

}

QLabel *DemoPromotedWidget::getLabel() const
{
    return label;
}

void DemoPromotedWidget::setLabel(QLabel *value)
{
    label = value;
    if(label)
        label->setText("some text");
}
```

---

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
...
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->widget->setLabel(ui->DemoLabel);
}
...
```

---

## second option:

Another much simpler way but it can only be done if the widget (QLabel) is added using Qt Designer as in this case using the method `showEvent()` and `findChild()`:

**demopromotedwidget.h**

```
#ifndef DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H
#define DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QWidget>

class DemoPromotedWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DemoPromotedWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
private:
    QLabel *label;
protected:
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event);
};

#endif // DEMOPROMOTEDWIDGET_H
```

**demopromotedwidget.cpp**

```
#include "demopromotedwidget.h"

DemoPromotedWidget::DemoPromotedWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void DemoPromotedWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)
{
    label = findChild<QLabel *>("DemoLabel");
    if(label)
        label->setText("some text");
    QWidget::showEvent(event);
}
```

---

## Update:

A new approach is that you create a form that is a QWidget and that has a `.ui`, `.h` and `.cpp`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As I said create a new class that unlike your initial code has a .ui, then open it with the help of Qt Designer and add the label

[image]

But it is also a class that you can promote as you did in your first approach.

[image]

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/50378537)

Comment: Hmm I didn't even think of this. Thanks. There must be a way to make DemoPromotedWidget selfaware of it's own UI elements though.... It seems silly for it not to. I even thought I would be able to just create a new Qt Designer form, and drag that into the widget toolbar, but I don't seem to be able to.

Comment: @Rick 
No, you do not confuse the classes with the objects created in the classes, it's like having a car factory (the class) and your car (the object that you use in Qt Designer) that you can change its color, the factory will not know about that action.

Comment: @Rick A possible new approach is that you create a new form and use that form in the main widget through the promotion.

Comment: I thought of making the new form too, but I don't know how to make it appear in the Qt Designer available widget list.

Comment: oh my gosh I love you! I wasn't thinking clearly, I was under the impression that I had to add the new form to the widget tool bar... forgot I could just promote a basic widget. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @eyllanesc please fix the link to your code in the answer: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/50378537